# Spring Standalone Apps | Logging

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am trying to put log in spring standalone application.Here is my code

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class Main {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    public String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        log.debug("Going to create HelloWord Obj");
        //Main p = (Main) context.getBean("hello");
        //System.out.println(p.getId());
        log.debug("Exiting the program");
        log.debug("Exiting the program1");


    }


}
```

My log4j.properties is

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C://log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

In above code log is working correctly.It is not working when i remove the comment from Main Class. It is throwing some additional info in log.out file which is shown below.Let me know the reason why it is throwing like this..?

```
Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
Initializing new StandardEnvironment
Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
Initializing new StandardEnvironment
Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd}
Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
Loading bean definitions
Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
Initializing new StandardEnvironment
Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
Looking for matching resources in directory tree [E:\eclipse-workspace\composer_projects\Spring_Standalone\bin\com\controller]
Searching directory [E:\eclipse-workspace\composer_projects\Spring_Standalone\bin\com\controller] for files matching pattern [E:/eclipse-workspace/composer_projects/Spring_Standalone/bin/com/controller/**/*.class]
Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/controller/**/*.class] to resources [file [E:\eclipse-workspace\composer_projects\Spring_Standalone\bin\com\controller\Main.class]]
Identified candidate component class: file [E:\eclipse-workspace\composer_projects\Spring_Standalone\bin\com\controller\Main.class]
Loaded 6 bean definitions from location pattern [spring.xml]
Bean factory for org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@27cd63: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1871f70: defining beans [main,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,hello]; root of factory hierarchy
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@653c7e]
Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@1588db6]
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'main'
Creating instance of bean 'main'
Eagerly caching bean 'main' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'main'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'hello'
Creating instance of bean 'hello'
Eagerly caching bean 'hello' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'hello'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@10ddb86]
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
Going to create HelloWord Obj
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'hello'
Exiting the program
Exiting the program1
```

Comment: and where do you see errors? I see that the application can't locate MessageSource, ApplicationEventMultiCaster and LifeCycleProcessor and that he's going to use the default one.

Comment: @childworld : sorry,additional information only i mean as errors.i need only the logger information,But it is throwing additional info.so let me know how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is still working.. At the bottom you can see

```
Exiting the program 
Exiting the program1
```

there is just additional log from the Spring framework. When the spring container is initialised it will log information of its own, as you see here.

I cant actually see any problem here.

---

If you want to remove the spring logging you can specify the logging level for a particular package like this in the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

Should only show warnings and errors.

I would change your conversionPattern to something like this also: `%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n`

This will give  alot more information and you will be able to see what package is logging what

Comment: :Okie..The log is printing.But i dont want any additional log written by spring container..how to achieve that?

Comment: :thanks..Its working and printing as below: 18:49:25,662 DEBUG Main:23 - Going to create HelloWord Obj
18:49:25,662 DEBUG Main:26 - Exiting the program
18:49:25,662 DEBUG Main:27 - Exiting the program1..How to avoid that time and 662..?

Comment: You can configure the log pattern however you want, take a look here for info on how it works: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: i configured my conversion pattern to log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n...so that it removes the time appended..thanks cowls for ur efforts...thanks very much

Comment: @sree no problem, though you might make your life easier by leaving the time and classname in there, but it all depends on your particurlar use case.

Comment: ya u r correct.I need just a basic logging.What u said may be i will exp it later.lolz..